# Flutter: run dart code after texture update

Tags: flutter, graphics, textures

Is it possible to run dart code after each Texture widget's backend texture update (e.g. on arrival of a video frame)?

Comment: You can not directly run dart code after each update of a Texture widget's backend texture in a Flutter app. The Flutter framework is designed to be highly efficient and optimized for rendering and UI updates. It doesn't provide hooks for arbitrary code execution on each frame update of a Texture widget.